# Array#zip not working (undefined method for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a table from 2 different sets of data

My Controller

```
@data = CompanyBorrower.find(params[:id])
@data1= @data.childs.all
@data2= @data.parents.all
```

The Table (a snippet)

```
            <% @data1.zip(@data2) do |f1,f2| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= f1.company_borrower1.name %></td>
                <td><%= f2.company_borrower2.name %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
```

But I get "undefined method `company_borrower2' for nil:NilClass".  If I remove one or the other set of data it works fine.

I think I know the issue; I think it is because the "data1" returns 5 rows, whilst "data2" would have 1 row.  If I switch, it works, but I only get one row!

So I (think) I know the issue, but have no idea how to resolve?

**Edit - Updated**

Note that company_borrower1 & company_borrower2 use the same model -

CompanyBorrower Model

```
has_many :childs, :class_name => 'Parent', :foreign_key => 'company_borrower_id'
has_many :parents, :class_name => 'Parent', :foreign_key => 'company_borrower_id1'
```

Parent Model

```
belongs_to :company_borrower1, :class_name => 'CompanyBorrower', :foreign_key => :company_borrower_id
belongs_to :company_borrower2, :class_name => 'CompanyBorrower', :foreign_key => :company_borrower_id1
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I do the following it works great, but it places what would be columns across rows.  I can work with that, but would still prefer to know how to achieve my original question for future reference

```
              <tr>
                <% @data1.each do |f1| %><td><%= f1.company_borrower1.name %></td><% end %>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <% @data2.each do |f1| %><td><%= f1.company_borrower2.name %></td><% end %>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show show us what `@data1` and `@data2` look like?

Comment: That's not the real code. First, we don't see company_borrower2 anywhere. And 2. shouldn't you use f1 and f2 inside the loop instead of data1 and data2? Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: There was some mistakes when I moved over the code - Now edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using ruby 2.3 or greater version you can make use of **Safe navigation operator (&.)** instead of **try** method

```
        <% @data1.zip(@data2) do |f1,f2| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= f1&.company_borrower1&.name %></td>
            <td><%= f2&.company_borrower2&.name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
```

The safe navigation operator **(&.)** will return nil if the object equals nil, otherwise it calls the method on the object..So, if you use the safe navigation operator, you need to make sure it will be called on the all methods.For example, I have used safe navigation operator on f2 object , f2&.company_borrower2 will return nil,but here we are calling agin name method on the return value of  f2&.company_borrower2.So in oreder to avoid the error, we need to call agian safe navigation operator.

Same thing applies on the usage of `try` method

```
       <% @data1.zip(@data2) do |f1,f2| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= f1.try(:company_borrower1).try(:name) %></td>
            <td><%= f2.try(:company_borrower2).try(:name) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Marvellous - Thank You  :)

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess would be to use `try` on what’s returned. So instead of this:

```
<td><%= data1.name %></td>
<td><%= data2.name %></td>
```

You should do something like:

```
<td><%= data1.try(:name) %></td>
<td><%= data2.try(:name) %></td>
```

Comment: Please note my code was wrong (now edited), but even with your changes to my code it still comes back with "undefined method `company_borrower2' for nil:NilClass"